# Python Program that gets stuck on the first number entered

Tags: python, string, loops

This is my code so far.

```
word = input('Enter a word: ')   
count = 0
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u']
for char in word:
    if char in vowels: 
        count += 1
while word != "":
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowel.')
  word = input('Enter a word: ') 
if not word:
  print("")
elif count == 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowel.') 
elif count > 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels.')
elif count < 1:
  print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowels.')
```

It should ask the user the user for a word and then print out how many lower case vowels the word has, and keep asking for a word until the input is an empty space.

I have the loop working, but when it asks you for the first time, and say you right "BOO" it will say BOO contains 2 vowels, and then every other word you enter continues to have 2 vowels, and it doesn't change according to the word. I guess you could say it gets stuck.

Here is an example

```
Enter a word: hello
hello contains 2 vowels.
Enter a word: me
me contains 2 vowels.
Enter a word: tomorrow
tomorrow contains 2 vowels.
Enter a word:
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: you do realise that you only count the vowels on the first input, and that it does not do that in your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign 0 to the **count** variable at each loop iteration, otherwise you will use a value from an old entered word. After that, you also need to count again the number of vowels in the new word.

Like this:

```
vowels = ['a' , 'e' , 'i' ,'o' , 'u']
word = input('Enter a word: ') 

while word != "":
        count = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in vowels: 
                count += 1
        print(word + ' contains ' + str(count) + ' vowel.')
        word = input('Enter a word: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the loop over each character to be within the loop where you get new input.

Answer (score 0):

```
for char in word:
    if char in vowels: 
        count += 1
```

is done before you enter your while loop.  Within the loop, you never reset `count`.  In order to get the expected result, either move the `for` loop into the `while`, or wrap it in a function and call it each time.